# Difference between these Constructor calling Statements?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
public class StudentFormMain {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StudentForm();
    }
}
```

And 2ND Class

```
public class StudentForm extends JFrame {
    public StudentForm(){
        setTitle("Admission Form");
        setSize(300,250);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```

My Question are

What is the difference between these statements

```
StudentForm studentform=new StudentForm();
```

and

```
new StudentForm()
```

First Statement Declare the Obj of that class and calls the Constructor, but in Second Statement only Constructor is calling.

**Note:** Result are Same

```
super(""); set the title of the frame
```

because it is calling  super class constructor.
we can also set the title by using the `setTitle("")` method

Please differentiate the methods also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
StudentForm studentform = new StudentForm();
```

constructs a new `StudentForm` instance and assign the reference to that instance to a variable `studentform`. So that you can call methods of the `StudentForm` instance later, such as `studentform.addContainerListener(xxx)`.

But code `new StudentForm()` just calls the constructor to create a new object instance, but don't hold the reference to that instance.

Comment: You are Saying  that instance to a variable What is means by  that instance to a variable ?

Comment: @Zu007 'instance' has the same meaning of 'object'. 'reference' is similar to 'pointer' in c/c++. And variable is variable. In code `StudentForm studentform = new StudentForm();`, `studentform` is a variable, which type is reference type, and points to the object(instance) created by `new StudentForm()` .

Answer (score 1):

```
new StudentForm();
```

Above variation calls just a constructor.

```
StudentForm studentform=new StudentForm();
```

Above variation is used when you want to access other methods than constructor in the class. In both the cases you contructor will be called regardless of you are using the `studentform` object or not.

For example if you class which has other method called `methodOne()`:

```
public class StudentForm extends JFrame {
    public StudentForm(){
        setTitle("Admission Form");
        setSize(300,250);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    public void methodOne()
    {
         System.out.println("In method one..");
    }
}
```

Then you can call it using:

```
StudentForm studentform=new StudentForm();
studentform.methodOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `new` keyword signifies the `instantiation/creation` of a `StudentForm` object. So

```
new StudentForm()
```

gives you an instance of `StudentForm` or simply a `StudentForm` object.

The only difference between

```
StudentForm studentform = new StudentForm();

and 

new StudentForm();
```

is that the former give you a `reference` to the new `StudentForm` object. The reference being `studentForm`

Answer (score 1):

`StudentForm studentform=new StudentForm();`

You are creating an Object of type StudentForm and assigning it to a reference called studentform (use camelCase i.e, studentForm instead of studentform for fields). Now, you can use studentForm to call some methods/access fields of the object.

`eg: studentForm.toString()`

If you don;t get a reference to the object, you can't cal the non-static methods on that object.

Answer (score 1):

Your First statement holding the reference of created instance, and the second statement don't have a reference for the created object. Other than this, there is no difference.